# Can I disable scrolling with the mouse click on a ScrollView in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, scrollview

I have a scrollview in Xamarin Forms [i've left a gif here so you can see it](https://im3.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-3-44a7d761fe83.gif) .
I'm using

```
scrollviewName.ScrollToAsync(0,0,true)
```

to have the scrolling with imagebutton clicks. But I can still scroll with the mouse. I've tried setting Orientation Property of my ScrollView to Neither but that just makes my scrollview not scrollable at all. Is there a way achieve what I'm asking or should I go for something else?

Comment: The context is not quite clear. just a guess: What about enabling scrolling temporary in the button click event ?

Comment: Is this a ScrollView or a CarouselView ?

Comment: @Cfun Sorry about the context. It's a ScrollView. And how can I disable/enable it in the events like you said?

Comment: @Cfun nvm, I found it but that's not what I'm looking for here. I want to disable scrolling with the mouse in the ScrollView. And I've tried doing what you said. It just makes my ScrollView go to the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Disable the scrollview like this

```
<ScrollView x:Name="myscroll" IsEnabled="False">
```

```
void Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   myscroll.ScrollToAsync(0, 1000, true);
}
```

[image]