# SkiaSharp canvas in ScrollView is still scrolling when drawing

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, scrollview, drawing, skiasharp

I cannot find a solution to this what seems a simple issue. I have created a simple skisharp finger painting area which is at the bottom of a scrollview in android Xamarin Forms.
this works how ever only for a second as the page will scroll as I draw on the canvas. Any way to stop this? as i cannot actually draw anything cause the line dissapears once scroll begins

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label x:Name="WeatherConditionLabel" Text="Weather/Condition" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
            <Grid>
                <Label Text="Day/Night:"
                   FontSize="Medium"
           VerticalOptions="Center" />
            </Grid>
            <Switch HorizontalOptions="Start" IsToggled="false" Scale="1.8" Margin="20"/>
            <Grid Margin="20,10,10,20">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.40*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.15*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.25*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.20*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label Text="Raining:"
                   FontSize="Medium"
           VerticalOptions="Center" />
                <CheckBox Grid.Column="1"
              Color="Turquoise"
              VerticalOptions="Center"
              Scale="1.6"
              x:Name="rainingCheck"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="2"
           Text="Snowing:"
                   FontSize="Medium"
           VerticalOptions="Center" />
                <CheckBox Grid.Column="3"
              Color="Turquoise"
              VerticalOptions="Center" 
              Scale="1.6"
              x:Name="snowingCheck"/>
                <Label Grid.Row="1"
           Text="Fog/Mist:"
                   FontSize="Medium"
           VerticalOptions="Center" />
                <CheckBox Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.Column="1"
              Color="Turquoise"
              Scale="1.6"
              VerticalOptions="Center"
              x:Name="FogMistCheck"/>
            </Grid>
            <Label x:Name="VehicleConditionImageLabel" Text="Vehicle Condition" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
            <xct:DrawingView x:Name="damageDrawing" HeightRequest="200" DefaultLineColor="green" ClearOnFinish="False" ></xct:DrawingView>
            <Grid Margin="5,5,5,5">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="35*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="35*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Button x:Name="greenBtn" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Green" />
                <Button Grid.Column="1" x:Name="amberBtn" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Yellow" />
                <Button Grid.Column="2" x:Name="rebBtn" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="red" Clicked="redBtnPressed" />
            </Grid>

            <Grid BackgroundColor="White">
                <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="canvasView"
                       HeightRequest="200"            
                       PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface" />
                <Grid.Effects>
                    <tt:TouchEffect Capture="True"
                        TouchAction="OnTouchEffectAction" />
                </Grid.Effects>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: You have to disable scrolling in order to draw on the canvas

Comment: @Jason how is this done im finding very little info online in regards to scrollview and canvas

Comment: You have to use a control like a button to signal when the user wants to draw.  Or place the canvas in a popup so it’s not scrollable

Comment: method OnTouchEffectAction is called when drawing, but how do i actually stop the scrolling within this method please @Jason

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65655658/can-i-disable-scrolling-with-the-mouse-click-on-a-scrollview-in-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [custom renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) to disable and enable the scrolling in the scrollview.

1. Declare the custom scrollview in the share project:

```
    public class MyScrollView : ScrollView
    {
        public bool ScrollingEnabled = true;
    }
```

2. Declare the custom renderer in the android project:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyScrollView), typeof(MyScrollViewRenderer))]

namespace XamarinFormsApp2.Droid
{
    public class MyScrollViewRenderer : ScrollViewRenderer
    {
        public MyScrollViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            /* nothing here */
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
        }

        public override bool OnInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
        {
            if (((MyScrollView)Element).ScrollingEnabled)
            {
                return base.OnInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }


        public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
        {
            if (((MyScrollView)Element).ScrollingEnabled)
            {
                return base.OnTouchEvent(ev);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

3. Use the custom view in the xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamarinFormsApp2"
             x:Class="XamarinFormsApp2.MainPage">
    <local:MyScrollView x:Name="scroll">
```

4. Disable the scrolling:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     scroll.ScrollingEnabled = false;
 }
```

Comment: Hi any idea as to how to implement in xamarin forms

Comment: I managed to understand customrenderers and this worked first time thank you so much!  The use was on the OnTouchEffectAction() skia method using TouchActionType.Pressed and TouchActionType.released to set scroll.ScrollingEnabled